# Fulltext search in SQL Server is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table **MyTable** in SQL Server and Full Text Search has been enabled on one varchar column "**Col1**". Available data is as follows:

```
Col1
----
ABC XYZ  
ABC PQR  
ABC CAN ZYZ
```

When I run the following select statements I get the result:

```
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Col1,' ("ABC" )')  
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Col1,' ("XYZ" )')  
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Col1,' ("ABC" AND "XYZ" )')
```

However, when I run the following statements it doesn't result in any data:

```
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Col1,' ("CAN" )')  
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Col1,' ("CAN*" )')  
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Col1,' "CAN*" ')  
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Col1,' ("ABC" AND "CAN" )')
```

I am not sure why it is not returning any data when I search with the word `CAN` even though the data is available in the table.

Track changes is automatic and populations schedule is run on daily basis. Available data in the table `MyTable` has been inserted 10 days ago.

Comment: I wouldn't be hugely surprised if `can` was a stopword and so not indexed.

Comment: I am not sure about stop words. How to avoid that as I want to see the data for the word CAN as well

Comment: I tried searching with the following statement also, but no result       SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Col1,' ("CAN" )', language 1033)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972991/how-to-get-a-list-of-stopwords-used-in-my-fulltext-catalog